Interpreting Monomorphisms as Final Objects?
A monomorphism is defined as a left-cancellative morphism. I am wondering if it may be rephrased in terms of universal properties. My first-shot attempt is

Let $\mathsf{C}$ be a category. Consider the category $\mathsf{C}_B$ whose objects are objects of $\mathsf{C}$ paired with a morphism to $B$, such as $(Z, f)$, and whose morphisms are just morphisms between the objects, say for $(Z, f)$, $(Z', g)$, $u : Z \to Z'$ such that $g \circ u = f$.

I claim that monos to $B$ are final objects in this category.

Let $(Z, f) \in \mathsf{C}_B$ and $\varphi$ be a mono from $A \to B$. We need to show there exists a unique morphism from $Z \to A$. Let $u, u'$ be such that $g \circ u = f$, $g \circ u' = f$. Since monos are left-cancellative, $u = u'$, as required.

So maybe this is correct. But is there any value to this interpretation, and is there a name for this category? Is this a slice category? But according to ProofWiki, the terminal object is the identity morphism.

You only argued for uniqueness, not existence. What if $C$ is the category of sets and $A$ is the empty set, for instance?

@DanDoel That is certainly a valid objection. But is the statement salvageable at all?

$\mathsf{C}_B$ is the slice category $\mathsf{C}/B$. I am not aware of a characterisation of monomorphisms using slice categories, but see here for a characterisation via pullbacks.

@n1lp0tence Maybe it's possible to do, but I'm skeptical it will be satisfying. You have to consider this: universal constructions are unique up to unique isomorphism. So, you probably can't have a single category where every monomorphism $A → B$ is a final object, because they would all have to be equivalent, but there can be multiple distinct monomorphisms between two objects. So you either have to forget about the meaningful differences, or tailor the category to just a specific monomorphism.

A regular monomorphism is a morphism that is an equalizer of some pair of morphisms. It can be proven that equalizers are always monomorphisms. Equalizers are a special kind of limit and thus final objects in a specific category. So in categories where all monomorphisms are regular, this is a solution to your question, in the vein of the latter option provided by Dan Doel in the comments on this question.

Another possibility is extremal monomorphisms, which obviously from the name involves a final object.
